# Problema en procedimiento almacenado de mysql (Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=')

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado, que intenta validar que el usuario y el correo que se está ingresando no exista en la base de datos antes de crear el registro (insertarlos) en la base de datos. El código que tengo es este:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ups_crearEmpresa`(IN `_usuario` VARCHAR(16), IN `_nombre` VARCHAR(30), IN `_ap1` VARCHAR(30), IN `_email` VARCHAR(50), IN `_password` TEXT, IN `_ip` TEXT)
BEGIN
set @token =SHA(_email+now()+_nombre);
set @pass = _password;

#Se valida que el correo no exista actualmente en la tabla de usuarios para empresa
SET @validaremail = (select email from empresas_usuariosprincipales where email=_email) ;
#Se valida que el usuario de la empresa no exista en la tabla de usuarios para empresa
set @validarusuario = (select usuario from empresas_usuariosprincipales where usuario=_usuario) ;


IF (_usuario  = @validarusuario ) THEN
set @a = 2;
SELECT @a codigo, 'El nombre de usuario ya existe.' as mensaje;

ELSE IF (_email =  @validaremail) THEN
set @a = 3;
SELECT @a codigo, 'La cuenta de correo electrónico ya existe.' as mensaje;
ELSE
#Se insertan los datos en la tabla empresas para obtener el id de la empresa
INSERT INTO empresas (TOKEN, fecharegistro, id_paquete) values (@token, now(), 1);
set @idempresa = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM empresas);

#se insertan los datos en la tabla de usuarios para empresas
INSERT INTO empresas_usuariosprincipales  (id_empresa, usuario, password, email, nombre, apellido1, ip) 
values (@idempresa, _usuario, _password, _email, _nombre, _ap1, _ip);

#se crea registro que contiene los privilegios para la empresa con las características del plan gratuito.
INSERT INTO  empresas_privilegios(id_empresa, perfilpublico, vercvpostulados, publicarofertas, ofertasmensuales, ofertasconsumidas, usuariosadicionales, usuariosconsumidos, mascaracorreo, mailbox, topofertas)
values (@idempresa, 1, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

#se crea el registro de la tabla de configuraciones
INSERT INTO empresas_config (id_empresa) values (@idempresa);

set @a = 1;
SELECT @a codigo, 'La cuneta se creó con éxito.' as mensaje, @token token;

END IF;
END IF;
END
```

En localhost me funciona de maravilla pero en el servidor de producción me arroja el siguiente error que no logro reparar :(

Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Realice un testo y el problema está en los if, me está mandando ese error al comparar el valor de la variable que recibo con el valor que le asingo de la consulta.

```
IF (**_usuario  = @validarusuario** ) THEN
```

En este enlace dicen posibles soluciones:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770074/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8-general-ci-implic

Ya actualicé mis tablas, una por una corriendo este comando, pero sigue sin funcionar:

```
ALTER TABLE users CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Gracias por sus comentarios. Un abrazo.

Comment: ¿Puedes confirmar a través de un `SHOW CREATE TABLE  latabla` ... que cada una de las tablas/columnas que participan en la procedure tienen la codificación adecuada? Claro está, me refiero a las tablas en el servidor. Si por algún motivo te interesaba mantener diferentes `COLLATE`, como dice la respuesta que enlazas, puedes cambiar el `COLLATE`  solamente en la procedure en ese caso.

Comment: En este punto estoy confundido, en realidad no se que tipo de codificación deberían de tener en verdad. Pero te comparto captura:  https://prnt.sc/ko28oo   y https://prnt.sc/ko28sq

Comment: Por la captura que te mando me doy cuenta que tienen info diferente (no se como se llaman ¿collate?, cual deberían de tener ambas para que mi procedimiento almacenado funcione correctamente?, y si no deseo modificar la tabla, como quedaría correctamente el procedimiento? porque también ya lo intenté pero sigue marcando el mismo error :(  Gracias.

Comment: Las `PROCEDURE` me parece que usan por defecto `utf8_general_ci`, entonces, lo que puedes hacer es cambiar el `COLLATE` de aquellas tablas / columnas que no lo sean **dentro de la `PROCEDURE`**. En las opciones 1 al 3 de la respuesta que enlazas se indica cómo hacerlo, puedes usar cualquiera de ellas.

Comment: Bueno entonces cual de las opciones tengo que ocupar?  utf8_general_ci, utf8_spanish2_ci o utf8_general_ci , ya me enredé :/ gracias de antemano.

Comment: A ver, es que eso depende de lo que quieras hacer. 1º. **Antes de cambiar el  `COLLATE` deberías informarte para qué sirve y cómo funciona.** 2º. Para hacer que el código funcione, **en la PROCEDURE**, debes igualar el `COLLATE`, sea haciendo que todas tus tablas/columnas tengan el mismo `COLLATE`  (si te conviene), sea estableciendo el mismo `COLLATE` en la `PROCEDURE`, como ya muestra la respuesta en inglés. Si iguales el `COLLATE`, cualquiera que sea, debería funcionar. La cuestión es que no admite `COLLATE` distintos. Debes igualar, sea de forma temporal o definitiva, eso depende de ti.

Comment: Ya encontré el problema. Por alguna razón, al exportar e importar la base de datos al servidor de producción se había cambiado el motor de la tabla. Tenía InnDB, solo lo cambié a MyISAM y quedó resuelto :) https://prnt.sc/ko2gls GRACIAS POR TODO!

Comment: Bien, me alegro. Lo puedes aportar como respuesta para que sirva de referencia a posibles usuarios con el mismo problema en un futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el problema. Por alguna razón, al exportar e importar la base de datos al servidor de producción se había cambiado el motor de la tabla. Tenía InnDB, solo lo cambié a MyISAM y quedó resuelto :) 
prnt.sc/ko2gls

GRACIAS POR TODO!